# Block Pyramids in Minecraft - closed formula for total number of blocks

Tags: sequences-and-series

The total number of blocks within pyramids on Minecraft doesn't quite correspond with [Square pyramidal numbers (on Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number). Because of the blocky nature of the environment, the "even rows" of the pyramid are missed out. So, a simple 3-block-high pyramid has $1 + 9 + 25 = 35$ blocks.

Hence the sum for a pyramid of height $n$ is given by $$\sum_{k=1}^n(2k - 1)^2$$

What's the corresponding shortcut formula for this series, involving $n^3$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure what I was thinking not asking Wolfram Alpha first:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1+to+k+of+%282k%E2%88%921%29%5E2

Wolfram doesn't show the substitutions it used, though; I'd expect you can get Mathematica to show them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we look for 
$$ P_n := \sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)^2 $$
for an $n$-layer pyramid. We have $(2k-1)^2 = 4k^2 - 4k + 1$, hence
\begin{align*} 
  P_n &= 4\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 - 4\sum_{k=1}^n k + n \\
      &= 4\cdot \frac 16\cdot n(n+1)(2n+1) - 4 \cdot \frac 12 n \cdot (n+1) + n\\
      &= \frac 23 \cdot (2n^3 + 3n^2 + n) - 2n² -2n + n\\
      &= \frac 43 n^3 + \frac 23 n - n\\
      &= \frac 13 n (4n^2-1)
\end{align*}

Comment: This gives the expected results. Thanks! I shouldn't been able to work out the substitution method myself... easy once you've spelled it out for me ;) next time...

Comment: You can also write that as $\frac16(2n-1)(2n)(2n+1)$.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, well we know that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$$

What you want is to skip out the $4$ and the $16$ and so forth layers right?

Well you actually mean to say "you want the odd layers" which is actually:

$\sum_{i=1}^n(2i-1)^2=1^2+3^2+5^2+\cdots$

Notice that:

$$\sum^n_{i=1}(2i-1)^2=\sum^n_{i=1}[4i^2-4i+1]=\sum^n_{i=1}4i^2-\sum^n_{i=1}4i+\sum^n_{i=1}1$$

This is of course $=4\sum^n_{i=1}i^2-4\sum^n_{i=1}i+n$

Which we know to be $=\frac{4}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)+n-4\sum^n_{i=1}i$

> Note that $$\sum^n_{i=1}i=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$$

Thus:

$$\sum^n_{i=1}(2i-1)^2=\frac{2}{3}n(n+1)(2n+1)+n-2n(n+1)$$

I leave you to do the factoring.

Comment: Thanks! First fraction should be $2/3$ rather than $1/3$ in your expansion. Then the numbers match.